# mingw installer virus detected on virustotal. false positive?

Tags: mingw, antivirus, virus, virus-scanning

A virus has been detected in mingw installer. Mainly in Virobot and TheHacker antivirus scanners.

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/aab27bd5547d35dc159288f3b5b8760f21b0cfec86e8f0032b49dd0410f232bc/analysis/1430491365/

I have searched on google as to why this is happening. I have found this.
http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Explanation-of-false-positives-for-viruses-in-mingw-get-setup-exe-td7582442.html

It seems that i'm not convinced with the answers to the topic. Because the third poster's opinion conflicts with the second poster. Should i click it? My only purpose is to run gcc on windows natively. Explanations are appreciated as to why or why not i should click this installer.

Comment: Some discussion on mingw-users votes that it's OK: http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Explanation-of-false-positives-for-viruses-in-mingw-get-setup-exe-td7582442.html

Comment: To tackle this use this tool https://github.com/uppusaikiran/virustotal-falsepositive-detector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this report in the past -- I'm fairly certain it is a false positive, but ultimately, it's your choice whether to run it or not. If you choose "not", then your alternative is a manual download and installation of a significant collection of separate packages; my own preference would be to run mingw-get-setup.exe, or at least to manually download and install the mingw-get package, and run mingw-get.exe to complete the installation.

To those who say I should be digitally signing code for which I receive no remuneration whatsoever, I have only one answer: digital signing is expensive; fund the effort, on my behalf, and I may consider it.